# Pintar coordenadas Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, canvas

Estoy intentando dibujar una serie de puntos (coordenadas), en Android Studio, pero solo consigo que me dibuje la última coordenada que le paso, aquí dejo el código que tengo

```
       class Vista extends View {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        public Vista(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            X_coordenadas.add((float) 100);
            X_coordenadas.add((float) 200);
            X_coordenadas.add((float) 300);

            Y_coordenadas.add((float) 100);
            Y_coordenadas.add((float) 200);
            Y_coordenadas.add((float) 300);


            for(int i=0; i<X_coordenadas.size();i++) {
                float  x  = X_coordenadas.get(i);
                float  y  = Y_coordenadas.get(i);

                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.planta2_as);

                canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);
                canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
                super.onDraw(canvas);
            }

        }
```

Si alguien me podría decir como hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho

Saludos

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que tienes la llamada a `super.onDraw(canvas);` dentro del bucle, por lo que termina ahí y pasa a ejecutar el código de la clase padre. Prueba a mover esa línea al final de todo, fuera del bucle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dibujar los puntos llama `super.onDraw(canvas);` fuera del bucle:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    X_coordenadas.add((float) 100);
    X_coordenadas.add((float) 200);
    X_coordenadas.add((float) 300);

    Y_coordenadas.add((float) 100);
    Y_coordenadas.add((float) 200);
    Y_coordenadas.add((float) 300);


    for (int i = 0; i < X_coordenadas.size(); i++) {
        float x = X_coordenadas.get(i);
        float y = Y_coordenadas.get(i);

        ...
        ...
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);

    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Noto que estas dibujando también un bitmap pero se esta posicionando siempre en 
`left=0`, `right=0`, por lo que siempre se mostrará en la esquina superior izquierda.

Puedes usar el valor de la misma coordenada x, y para mostrar la imagen:

```
...

  for (int i = 0; i < X_coordenadas.size(); i++) {
            float x = X_coordenadas.get(i);
            float y = Y_coordenadas.get(i);

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.planta2_as);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y, paint); //* aquí
            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);

        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

   ...
```

tendrías algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo había solucionado, era exactamente eso, muchas gracias de todos modos, el bitmap quiero que siempre se dibuje en la esquina superior solo quiero quería que variase el punto